# What is the correct way to create toolbar buttons with Xcode 12

Tags: nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am trying to recreate an apps toolbar using the new XCode12/macos11 capabilities but can't seem to reproduce the same result that the Apple apps get.

You can see my app on the left with the smaller icon, Xcode 12 in the middle and Safari on the right.  I was under the impression macOS11 would automatically resize things but this does not seem to be happening.

I have followed the Apple ToolbarSample and regardless of whether I use a custom NSView and Square button or if I use a ToolbarItem in Interface builder the result is different.  Using a ToolbarItem in Interfacebuilder results in a bigger icon again and none of the toolbar items I create show any mouseover shadow.  What kind of button are they using and how are they creating them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK - FYI DTK builds of the Apple apps have the same size icons so there I guess there are still some difference in the Intel macOS builds.